# How to add components to vue on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

So I have a page with a button. When this button is clicked I would like text to appear, and everytime the button is clicked I would like the text to appear like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<v-row>
    <component
    v-for="(component, index) in components"
    :key="index"
    :is="component"/>
</v-row>

<v-row justify="left" class="ml-3">
    <v-btn class="elevation-7 grey darken-1 btn" @click="add">Click me</v-btn>
</v-row>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('component', {
        template: '<p>component</p>'
    })

export default {
        data: () => {
            return {
                components: [Comp]
            };
        },

        methods: {
            add: function () {
                this.components.push(Comp)
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

Yet when I click the button nothing appears? I would really appreciate some help as I do not understand this.

**UPDATE**

I checked console and I am seeing this:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

This error then points to `this.components.push(Comp)` . In vue.config.js I added `runtimeCompiler: true` yet this error still persists and the text does not appear.

This is all done on vuejs + electron.

Comment: try this example : https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-williams-56jnb?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using vue2.

Because the compiler is not included in runtime-only builds, you have to set an alias for vue.

```
    // if you are using webpack
    build: {
        extend(config, ctx){
            config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common';
        }
    },
    
    // if you are using vite
    vite: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.common'
            }
        },
    }
```

for more details, please view the [docs: Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)